# Align bottom axis of multiple cartesian and polar coordinate plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

How can I vertically align the two plots `p1` (cartesian coordinates) and `p2` (polar coordinates) at their x-axis (lower edge of their plot windows), which are currently distributed horizontally and centered vertically using `grid.arrange`?

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(trans = factor(am)))

p1 <- p + geom_bar(aes(x="", fill=trans)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=gray(1:2/3))
p2 <- p + geom_bar(aes(x="", fill=trans)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=gray(1:2/3)) +
  coord_polar(theta="y")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow=1)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: the two plots are distributed horizontally and centered vertically (not horiz). Are you trying to move the polar plot to be on the lower edge of the plot window? It might be nice if you upload thumbnails of (1) what you get, and (2) an edited version with what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the response using your language. Yes, I'd like the bottom edge of the two plots to be aligned.

Comment: Since their relative aspect ratios appear to be solid, you might be able to define a 2x2 matrix instead of 1x2, leaving the upper-right corner unused. It won't be a perfect bottom-alignment, but it'll be closer than it is now. See "Basic Strategy" in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html